# How do I pass a list of packages to aptitude and resolve conflicts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, aptitude

How do I pass a list of packages to aptitude so that I can resolve the conflicts interactively?

Answer (score 0):

You can just run aptitude with no parameters, and resolve conflicts interactively through the aptitude UI.

Comment: I ended up using apt-get since it didn't complain so I cannot reproduce the situation. For future, do you mean "cat foo.txt | xargs aptitude install; aptitude" would work?

Comment: No, I mean run `aptitude` by itself.